# Using KnockoutJS, how to bind data to 2 different <select> tags from the same view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 2 select tags on my view.html like so

```
<select id="first" data-bind="options: firstDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: value"></select>
<select id="second" data-bind="options: secondDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: value"></select>
```

And something like this in my viewmodel.js

```
var firstDropdownOptions = ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 111, title: 'Option 1' },
        { value: 222, title: 'Option 2' },
        { value: 333, title: 'Option 3' }
    ]);

var secondDropdownOptions = ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 1, title: 'Option New 1' },
        { value: 2, title: 'Option New 2' },
        { value: 3, title: 'Option New 3' }
    ]);
```

I am unable to bind data to both my `<select>` tags. Only the first `<select>` tag works properly. Also, if I move the #second `<select>` tag before the #first `<select>`, then the #second shows correct data, but not the #first `<select>`.

How do I bind data to both my `<select>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your bindings you are using `value: value`. This means that values of both `select` elements are bound to the same model property, called `value`. You are using different arrays with different objects, so single value cannot function correctly. Try using two different properties for storing values, for example:

```
var vm = {
    firstDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 111, title: 'Option 1' },
        { value: 222, title: 'Option 2' },
        { value: 333, title: 'Option 3' }
    ]),
    secondDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 1, title: 'Option New 1' },
        { value: 2, title: 'Option New 2' },
        { value: 3, title: 'Option New 3' }
    ]),
    // property for storing selected value of firstDropdownOptions:
    selectedFirstOptionValue: ko.observable(''),   
    // property for storing selected value of secondDropdownOptions:
    selectedSecondOptionValue: ko.observable('')
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And in your HTML bind properties `selectedFirstOptionValue` and `selectedSecondOptionValue` respectively (properties will contain objects from your arrays):

```
<select id="first" data-bind="options: firstDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedFirstOptionValue"></select>
<select id="second" data-bind="options: secondDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedSecondOptionValue"></select>
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0ocrbo/)

Comment: The changes you suggested fixed my issue. But I'm still not sure why this is happening. I agree that both `<select>`s should not be bound to the same model property `value`, but `value` also belongs to 2 different observable arrays here. Why does this not work then? Also, if I use `value1` and `value2` properties in `firstDropdownOptions` and `secondDropdownOptions` respectively, shouldn't this fix the problem too then? I'm just curious. I also found an alternate way out, I've added a new answer below.

Comment: How do I pre-select an option in the dropdown when I'm working with array of complex objects? I've asked a question for this [separately here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633784/how-to-pre-select-option-in-select-dropdown-when-working-with-array-of-objects-i).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to dotnetom's answer, this worked for me too.

Instead of using different properties for storing the selected values in my viewmodel.js, I used `firstDropdownOptions().value` and `firstDropdownOptions().value` in view.html instead.

view.html

```
<select data-bind="options: firstDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: firstDropdownOptions().value"></select>
<select data-bind="options: secondDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: secondDropdownOptions().value"></select>
```

viewmodel.js

```
var vm = {
firstDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 111, title: 'Option 1' },
        { value: 222, title: 'Option 2' },
        { value: 333, title: 'Option 3' }
    ]),
    secondDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray([
        { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
        { value: 1, title: 'Option New 1' },
        { value: 2, title: 'Option New 2' },
        { value: 3, title: 'Option New 3' }
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0ocrbo/2/).