# How to pre-select option in select dropdown when working with array of objects in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

This is actually related to a question I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625827/using-knockoutjs-how-to-bind-data-to-2-different-select-tags-from-the-same-vi/34625999#34625999). But since, this was in a slightly different context, I thought it was best if I created a new question altogether.

I know how to pre-select an option in the dropdown when I'm working with a simple array of strings.

**Array of strings**

*View*

```
<select id="first" data-bind="options: firstDropdownOptions, value: selectedFirstOptionValue"></select>
```

*View Model*

```
firstDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray(['USA','UK','Other']);
selectedFirstOptionValue: ko.observable('UK');
```

..but how do I pre-select an option if it's an array of objects?

**Array of objects**

*View*

```
<select id="second" data-bind="options: secondDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedSecondOptionValue"></select>
```

**View model**

```
secondDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray([
    { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
    { value: 1, title: 'Option New 1' },
    { value: 2, title: 'Option New 2' }, // I want this option selected initially
    { value: 3, title: 'Option New 3' }
]);
// similarly, how to pre-select the 3rd option in this case?
selectedSecondOptionValue: ko.observable('')
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0ocrbo/3/) here.

I've tried passing the entire object here, the value only as an integer. I even thought maybe if I try to render the `<select>` dropdown in a way that I can set the attributes explicitly, then maybe I can try and manipulate the `selected` attribute for it. But I did not get the expected results. Here is the [fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0ocrbo/6/).

```
<select data-bind="foreach: secondDropdownOptions">
    <option data-bind="attr: { text: title, value: value}"></option>
</select>
```

In this case, the text does not bind, although the value attribute binds to each `<option>` in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the `optionsValue` parameter. According to the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) :

> ...However, if you want to let the user choose from an array of
>   arbitrary JavaScript objects (not merely strings), then see the
>   optionsText and optionsValue parameter.

The select for an array of objects:

```
<select id="second" data-bind="options: secondDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'title', optionsValue: 'value', value: selectedSecondOptionValue"></select>
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyjqz6n4/2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I completely missed the `optionsValue` parameter. I was also wrongly using the index of the array to pre-select options, whereas I should have been using the actual "value" from the array instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make the options list a separate variable that can be used by both of your observables.

```
var options = [
    { value: -1, title: 'Select Type' },
    { value: 1, title: 'Option New 1' },
    { value: 2, title: 'Option New 2' }, // I want this option selected initially
    { value: 3, title: 'Option New 3' }
];

var vm = {
  secondDropdownOptions: ko.observableArray(options),
  selectedSecondOptionValue: ko.observable(options[2])
};
```

Probaby what you really want to do is use the `optionsValue` binding, as Bogdan Goie suggested, in which case your initialization is simply

```
  selectedSecondOptionValue: ko.observable(2)
```

Incidentally, you might also want to look at the [`optionsCaption` parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters) as an alternative to your `-1` option.

Comment: Yes, I agree. `-1` was more like a specific project requirement for some reason, but I will be removing that and using `optionsCaption` instead. Thanks for the tip.